# Traversing DataRelations in ASP.NET Gridview with ADO.NET and .NET 4

Tags: asp.net, linq, ado.net

When one has a Gridview and two datatables and one wishes to get the parent row and bind it to a gridview, how would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to resolve the issue. One can cast the datasource to the typed dataset and bind the linq object to the column. A sample solution follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }

    private void BindGridView()
    {
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.deb_MenuRecipeTableAdapter mr = new DataSet1TableAdapters.deb_MenuRecipeTableAdapter();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.deb_MenuRecipeCategoryTableAdapter mrc = new DataSet1TableAdapters.deb_MenuRecipeCategoryTableAdapter();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.rec_RecipeCategoryTableAdapter rc = new DataSet1TableAdapters.rec_RecipeCategoryTableAdapter();
        mr.Fill(ds.deb_MenuRecipe);
        mrc.Fill(ds.deb_MenuRecipeCategory);
        rc.Fill(ds.rec_RecipeCategory);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataMember = ds.deb_MenuRecipe.TableName;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

On can then resolve the reference through the dataset using Server tags:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        AllowPaging="true" BorderStyle="Dotted" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="1" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="MenuRecipeID" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# ((TestingPlatform.DataSet1) GridView1.DataSource).deb_MenuRecipe[Container.DataItemIndex].deb_MenuRecipeCategoryRow.MenuRecipeCategoryID %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# ((TestingPlatform.DataSet1) GridView1.DataSource).deb_MenuRecipe[Container.DataItemIndex].deb_MenuRecipeCategoryRow.rec_RecipeCategoryRow.RecipeCategory %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Please note that in the solution the Namespace that the project and aspx file exists in is TestingPlatForm. The Gridview datasource is then Cast to the typed Dataset type and we traverse the row that is being bound by the gridview through the linq extensions for the relations.

I hope this solution is of use to others who may still be using ADO.NET.